# Using Try Catch to convert value

Tags: c#, sql

In the following example below, I am returning a value from a database and converting the value to a double, if it falls over due to being NULL, then 0 is being set as the default value.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), conn))
{
    try
    {
        this.value = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        this.value = 0;
    }
}
```

By using a Try Catch in this instance, would this be considered bad practice?  What would be a better way to handle this scenario?

Comment: You could use `double.TryParse` instead. Not necessarily *better* practice, but it's faster than exception handling.

Comment: @Nolonar Sure it's the better practice. **Don't use** exceptions to control the flow.

Comment: @DHN Point taken. Thank you for pointing that out :)

Comment: You also should consider using `nullable type`: `double?`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> By using a Try Catch in this instance, would this be considered bad practice?

Absolutely. Aside from anything else, you're returning 0 if *anything* fails, not just if the return value is null. (Do you *really* want to continue as if everything's fine if it turns out that the entire table's been deleted?)

If you want to detect a null return value, you should do so explicitly:

```
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
return result == null ? 0d : (double) result;
```

This will *still* throw (and deliberately) if there's a non-null return value which *isn't* a `double`. You should know what type your query should return, and fail if it turns out you've got the wrong type.

Answer (score 5):

You want [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx), this returns a boolean and you pass an uninitialized double variable into it with the out parameter which gets assigned the value.

Comment: I disagree strongly, for reasons I've already outlined on the comment on Darren's answer. `TryParse` is appropriate when you've got a *string* to convert. `ExecuteScalar` shouldn't be returning a string if the value is naturally a `double`, and there's no reason to introduce string conversions.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry I answered before you, but you are of course correct and I have learned something new, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be considered bad practice. Try Catch is not meant for program flow like this. If another exception was thrown, then you would still catch it and set the value to 0.

Check specifically for your program flow. Explicitly handling null is more efficient, and easier to follow.